# How to save div elements in form post

Tags: django

I have a form currently with a text area.

However, I want it to have rich-text formatting (bold, bullet points etc..) and for that, I have found Quill, which is amazing.

I'm not sure how to get the contents of div id=editor and save that to the Django function, because it won't be part of the post, will it?

```
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Usually the trick is to have a hidden form element `<input type="hidden">` and you synchronize with some javascript in between the two.

Comment: Ah so you wouldn't try and actually save the values in the editor div, but would copy whatever is included in editor to a textarea?

Comment: indeed, that is how other UI plugins like `select2` for example work as well: they do some magic with divs en css, and then when the user clicks on an option, copy this to a hidden `<select>` item. I agree it is not very elegant, but probably it is the most robust.